# Values of c for which the function has a horizontal/vertical asymptote

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, asymptotics

Given $$f(x) = \frac1{x^2 + 2x + c}$$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$,
find values of $c$ for which $f$ has a horizontal asymptote.

Also for what values of $c$ does the function have no vertical asymptote, one vertical asymptote and two vertical asymptotes?

Thanks.

Comment: Just recall the definition of asymptotes and apply that following the given hint. If you can show your work here, I will give a check to it. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

For horizontal asymptotes consider

- $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)$

For vertical asymptotes consider the roots for

- $x^2 + 2x + c=0$

Answer (score 1):

There's a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$ $\forall c$.

This is because your function cannot equal $0$ as everything being affected by $x$ is on the denominator.

With vertical asymptotes, I'll summarise how you can easily work out how many each will have:

Let $x^2+2x+c=(x+p)(x+q)$
The discriminant ($b^2-4ac$) for these equations is $4-4c$

If $4-4c=0$, we get one vert asymp, this is just when $c=1$

If $4-4c>0$, we get two vertical asymptotes, when $c<1$

If $4-4c<0$, we get no vertical asymptote, when $c>1$.

The reason this method works, is because setting the discriminant to $>0,=0,<0$ will tell you an equation will have $2,1,0$ distinct real solutions respectively.

Comment: @RhyHughes As a suggestion, It should be better to do not give full answer for problem for which no effort is shown by the asker.

Comment: @gimusi Understood.

Comment: Thanks, we should give some good hints at first and then add some more details after some effort has been shown. of course that's only my point of view given as suggestion. Bye